# haproxy CD flags with browser, not with curl

Tags: haproxy

Issuing the same url request, from the same workstation to the same haproxy server:

- with a browser (tried Chrome and Firefox): haproxy log shows `CD` flags
- with curl: haproxy log shows `--`

Both requests get a full answer back - no data is truncated.

According to [this](http://haproxy.tech-notes.net/8-5-session-state-at-disconnection/), flags `CD` mean

> The client unexpectedly aborted during data transfer. This can be
>   caused by a browser crash, by an intermediate equipment between the
>   client and haproxy which decided to actively break the connection, by
>   network routing issues between the client and haproxy, or by a
>   keep-alive session between the server and the client terminated first
>   by the client.

Given that I'm issuing both queries from the same workstation, I would exclude any influence of "intermediate equipment" or "routing issues".
The difference seems to lie in how the two clients open and close the connection.

Any clue anyone?

Comment: any redirect that maybe curl isn't following?

Comment: I would start with the developer tools in the browser and debug in curl to see what headers are sent to the client and how the client is responding to them.

Answer (score 0):

almost certainly this:

> a keep-alive session between the server and the client terminated first by the client.